# How do I use the Stanford POS Tagger in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I want to use the Stanford POS Tagger 3.5.0 in my android application project. I am using Eclipse for android app development. Can anyone tell me how to do so? I'm new in android development so could really use some help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  According to the [Stanford POS page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml):

> The system requires Java 1.8+ to be installed.

Comment: thats wrong. you can use an older version e.g. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-postagger-full-2014-08-27.zip